# How can I print on this POS using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, pos

[image]

I try this function but doesn't work

```dart
Future<void> _connect(BluetoothDevice device) async {
  if (device == null) {
    show('No device selected.');
  } else {
    bluetooth.isConnected.then((isConnected) {
      if (!isConnected!) {
        bluetooth.printCustom("thermal pinter", 0, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          bluetooth.printCustom("Welcome", 0, 1);
          bluetooth.printNewLine();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on SO!
I don't know much about bluetooth printing or if the methods you're using exists and are used correctly, but at least I can notice that your code is sending the order to print when the printer is NOT connected.
See here:

```
if (!isConnected!) {
  //the code below is executed only if isConnected is false, but seems like you want it to be the opposite
  bluetooth.printCustom("thermal pinter", 0, 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    bluetooth.printCustom("Welcome", 0, 1);
    bluetooth.printNewLine();
  }
}
```

Taking for granted that the code is correct, the line `if (!isConnected!)` will perform the code in the `{}` that follows only when the printer is not connected. Try removing the `!` before `isConnected` and see if it works. Again, this is simply a wild guess judging on your variables name and such, I can't really say that the problem lies there.